# driver.navigate().to("url") is not working in Chrome 64 and driver chrome 2.35;

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, automation, webdriver

I don't know what happened actually. Suddenly My Test step Do not pass.

```
public void gotoRolePage() {
    driver.navigate().to("url");

}

public void gotoRolePage() {
    driver.get("url");
}



 Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1) on 
port 10252
Only local connections are allowed.
Feb 11, 2018 12:54:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSess
ion
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the rem
ote end
Feb 11, 2018 12:54:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSess
ion
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[426.532][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.935
[426.533][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
[426.536][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.004
```

I have tried both of this function. No Luck...It was working Perfectly Last day.

This is maven Project with cucumber

ChromeDriver 2.34.522940, and Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What is happening on calling that method?

Comment: The step stack for some time than show failed..but the function successfully navigates to url. :/ really confused.....

I have run my test on other pc its working perfectly

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace please.

Comment: Update the browser and use latest chromedriver.exe

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome 64 is most updated version till now.
by the way, I have solved this issue by using chrome version 63.

Answer (score 1):

***At last, I am able to solve the issue by downgrade my chrome.
Now it's perfectly working like before with ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (Chrome 63).***

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same thing happening.  I found that doing driver.get(url), and then doing another driver.get(url) in the same test method was the reason why.  Very frustrating, but I also found that downgrading chrome worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated today all my driver again.
Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181
And ChromeDriver 2.37.544315

till Now it's working fine.I think they solved the problem in new update

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `driver.get(url)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.